# Oracledb NodeJS temp table and select execution failing

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle

I have the query below:

```
call IFSAPP.Budget_Template_Row_Util_API.Insert_Period_Focus_Tmp_Tbl('xxxx',1);

     select ITEM_CATEGORY KATEGORI,CURRENCY_CODE,ACCOUNT_DESC HESAP_TANIMI,CODE_C_DESC GIDER_ACIKLAMA,CODE_F PROJE_ID,

     CODE_F_DESC PROJE_ACIKLAMA,PA03 DONEM1,PA06 DONEM2,PA09 DONEM3,PA12 DONEM4,LINE_TOTAL TOPLAM,

     IFSAPP.XXXX_STRATEJIK_AMAC_API.Get_Aciklama(AMAC_KODU) ST_AMAC_ACIKLAMA,

     IFSAPP.XXXX_STRATEJIK_AMAC_API.Get_Hedef(AMAC_KODU) ST_AMAC_HEDEF from IFSAPP.BUDGET_TEMPLATE_LINE

     where COMPANY= 'xxxx' and BUDGET_PROCESS_ID= '2017-01-R' and BUDGET_TEMPLATE_ID ='2017-01-R-3009-0003'
```

The first line starts a temp table and inserts a period and the next select query starts to fill the temp table. Here I am not able to execute the query on nodejs oracledb while the same query works fine on pl/sql developer.

I get the following output:

> ora:00933 sql command not properly ended

Comment: Any console output, errors?

Comment: ora:00933 sql command not properly ended @MilanVelebit